# How do I exit (Microchip Pic18fxxxx rs232 BTFSS PIR1,RCIF) Loop when no data is present (Assembly Mplab Mpasm)

Tags: pic, uart, microchip, rs232, assembly

```
Received:   
    BTFSS   PIR1,RCIF    ; Gets Stuck in this loop! ; () checks for received data   
    GOTO     Received    

    MOVFF   RCREG,TEMP
    BCF     PIR1,RCIF
    BCF     PIR2,TMR3IF
```

It gets stuck in this loop until it receives data. Everything works well except if it gets into the loop with no data. Is there a timeout in assembly language, I have looked for data everywhere but no answers.

Comment: probably the easiest solution is not to loop while waiting for data ... check if data has arrived ... do other things if it has not arrived

Comment: I like your answer if my program would only cooperate, this project has multiple timers, I2C and pin inputs interrupts, unless there is away of differentiating an initiate it can get into the loop

Comment: Step back from the code, and **design** your software. Approach a solution by algorithms, not by typing source code. Only if you are confident that your algorithm will work, translate it into code. -- There are multiple ways to do it, one "big" loop" with several conditional parts, state machines, interrupts. Research, experiment, learn, and finally decide.

Comment: Write an UART receive ISR which handles the reception of data. Otherwise stay in the main loop.

Comment: I have a main loop that does what you say but I have to interrupt that main loop to address the random serial port. I have researched for 2 weeks and can not find an answer.  I am using a wireless serial port so it can cause issues I am trying to address By the way there are 15,000 lines of code not a simple problem.

Comment: Below is the code I finally got to work the way I wanted it too. I gave much thought overnight and came up with this ANSWER.  Thanks to all who inspired my Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
       HI_INT_VECTOR    CODE    0x0008
      bra   HighInt     

       LOW_INT_VECTOR   CODE    0x0018
      bra   LowInt      
      CODE
  HighInt:
       MOVFF RCREG,TEMP
       TSTFSZ TEMP
      call RECEIVE_DATA
      retfie    FAST

 LowInt:
 retfie 


   RECEIVE_DATA:


INFO..This Statement caused problems with my first Data Sent.
    ;;;;  HighInt:
    ;;;;  MOVFF RCREG,TEMP
;;;;  TSTFSZ TEMP
    ;;;;  call RECEIVE_DATA .........TO CORRECT IT THIS IS WHAT I DID.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

TO START MY TRANSMISSION I SEND A NUMBER SOMETHING THAT
I WOULD NOT NORMALLY EXPECT TO SEND AND CHECK THE NUMBER.
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
AFTER AN INTERUPT CALL's MY   "RECEIVE_DATA"    IT COMPARE THE NUMBER,
IF THE NUMBER DOES NOT MATCH IT EXITS THE PROCEEDURE... ExitPort:
I HAD TRIED IT EARLIER WITHOUT A CHECK, AND THE FIRST DATA INFO
I SENT WAS NOT CORRECT, SO THIS WILL NOT ONLY START MY DATA INFO
BUT WILL PREVENT FALSE INTERUPTS FROM GETTING INTO THE
"Received:"    Loop Forever

Next Line "Data_Check:" checks number sent matches the received number.
If not then exit routine "GOTO  ExitPort", Probably "RANDOM DATA".
Below  "Received:"  is the Loop that begins an endless loop
if no data is present, Waiting for something that may not
come for hours, Another serial transmission to get out of the loop!
Once past "Received:" then I separate individual transmissions.

```
    Data_Check:
    MOVLW   b'11101101'
    CPFSGT   TEMP
    GOTO    ExitPort
     MOVLW   b'11101111'
    CPFSLT    TEMP
    GOTO    ExitPort    

    CLRF    TEMP 
    CLRF    INFO_COUNT
    MOVLW   b'00000110'
    ADDWF   INFO_COUNT

    Received:   
    BTFSS   PIR1,RCIF           
    GOTO     Received 
 
    MOVFF   RCREG,TEMP
    BCF     PIR1,RCIF   
    BCF     PIR2,TMR3IF 
    DECF    INFO_COUNT
    MOVLW    b'00000101'
    CPFSLT   INFO_COUNT
    GOTO    FIRST_NUM
    MOVLW    b'00000100'
   CPFSLT   INFO_COUNT
   GOTO    SECOND_NUM 
   MOVLW    b'00000011'
    CPFSLT   INFO_COUNT
   GOTO    THIRD_NUM
   MOVLW    b'00000010'
    CPFSLT  INFO_COUNT
    GOTO    FOURTH_NUM
    GOTO    ExitPort
    FIRST_NUM:
    MOVFF   TEMP,First_Info
    GOTO    Received   
    SECOND_NUM:
     MOVFF   TEMP,Second_Info
     GOTO    Received
     THIRD_NUM:
     MOVFF  TEMP,Third_Info
     GOTO    Received
     FOURTH_NUM:
     MOVFF  TEMP,Fourth_Info
     MOVLW    b'01000001'
       CALL     Additional_Data_Sorting
       ExitPort: 
     BCF        PIR2,TMR3IF
     BCF        PIR1,RCIF 
     BCF       INTCON,GIE 
     CLRF      First_Info
     CLRF      Second_Info
     CLRF      Third_Info
     CLRF      Fourth_Info
      RETURN

       Additional_Data_Sorting:
       ;;Code as required
       RETURN
```

Comment: Hmmmm For me hard to read with all these uppercase letters and uncomment source code....

Answer (score 0):

My final solution of creating a TIMEOUT for the Serial Port endless loop............
Trial and Error!!............
You may question my use of EQU vs RES declarations but I found out that the EQU
can be used anywhere in the program code not just limited to the Reserved Area.
I have run out of Space (103 RES Declarations) for any more RES without causing problems with my, "PCL" kept moving around. Just a comment because I am sure someone will
not like it. Anyway my ANSWER!

First an interrupt from the HighInt: Calls the Serial Port Receiver. Using
TSTFSZ to make sure the RCREG has data from RS232.

```
    HighInt:
   Uart_check  EQU  0X16
   MOVFF RCREG,Uart_check
   TSTFSZ Uart_check         
   CALL SERIAL_RECEIVER
   retfie   FAST


SERIAL_RECEIVER:
START_OF_SERIAL_RECIEVED:
UART_TIME     EQU   0X19  ;Declaring a Variable
UART_TIMER    EQU   0X20    
CLRF    UART_TIME         ;Making sure the Variables are 0x00
CLRF    UART_TIMER
MOVLW   B'11111111'
MOVWF   UART_TIME
MOVWF   UART_TIMER
```

Could not use "MOVLW Wreg" while in the Receiver loop thereforth the "BTFSS Uart_check,7"  Any use of CPFSGT  CPFSLT  caused a problem because they were proceeded with MOVLW.........and TSTFSZ   DECFSZ  INCFSZ  didn't work either.
"UART_TIME" was Set at b'11111111' and then at b'01111111'  would "Goto  INCREMENT_UART_TIME" then be reset to b'11111111' using  "CLRF UART_TIME"
"DECF UART_TIME" no use of Wreg Allowed. Then by using "DECFSZ   UART_TIMER"
this allow 255 times for the "UART_TIME" TO be recycled and counted down. Until "UART_TIMER" reached Zero. Giving enough time that the 9600 baud rate would finish before the "UART_TIMER" reached Zero. Checking each loop with "BTFSS  PIR1,RCIF"
If the "UART_TIMER" reached Zero before any data appeared it would "GOTO"
Exit_Port:

```
Receiver:              
DECFSZ  UART_TIME
BTFSS   UART_TIME,7
GOTO    INCREMENT_UART_TIME  ;Keep waiting for data or UART_TIMER Zero's

Receiver_Return:
BTFSS   PIR1,RCIF       ;loop checks for received data 
GOTO     Receiver

BCF     PIR1,RCIF 
MOVFF   RCREG,TEMP_READ  

ExitPort:

    RETURN


INCREMENT_UART_TIME:
CLRF      UART_TIME
DECF      UART_TIME
DECFSZ    UART_TIMER
GOTO      Receiver_Return      
GOTO      ExitPort
```